# auto login to drupal using hidden form

Tags: users

I want to login to drupal site from another site ( both site hosted on different server)

This is html form to login to drualsite.

```
<form id="sso_form" method="POST" action="http://www.drupalsite/user/login">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="username">
  <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="password">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_login">
  <input type="hidden" name="op" value="Log in">
</form>
```

submitting form using javascript.

But this is not working for me.

Any idea or another way to do it?

Comment: Drupal forms have CSRF protection to stop forms being submitted from external sources. I would recommend you come up with a different way to solve your problem, anything you could do to make your current JavaScript work would leave your site vulnerable. The Services module would be the obvious choice

Comment: Creating custom module is also a option.See the implementation here https://www.hypnosisdownloads.com/which-downloads/login and https://www.hypnosisdownloads.com/ask-mark/login
But I would prefer to go with the services module.